# It was only 5 years ago when(that?) I became an engineer

Tags: exam-questions

> It was only 5 years ago when I became an engineer.

A friend of mine told me that the *when* used in above sentence is incorrect and it should be replaced by *that* is it true ? I [checked the ngram](https://goo.gl/sVR5qZ) and found both of these being in use.

Comment: Be aware that Ngrams is a blunt instrument.  It's perfectly acceptable to begin a sentence like "It was years ago, when I was a younger man, that..." and it will show up in Ngrams, but that's not the issue you're asking about in your question.

Answer (score 2):

The use of *that* instead of *when* seems correct in the context of this sentence.

However the grammar checker in my old version of Microsoft Office (set to US English), does not flag the use of the word *when*.

This could be a case of how the sentence reads. The word *when* may be acceptable. but *that* flows better and is the way I would phrase it.

If this was a partial sentence, then the use of *when* may be acceptable, for example:

"It was only 5 years ago when I became an engineer, but prior to that ...."

Answer (score 1):

It  may  be acceptable  but grammarians  insist  that  ago and  when  should not come side by side.

> **It was only five years ago that I became an engineer**

**It was five years ago  that I started speaking English**  is the preferred form.

I think native speakers use this way.